# JQuery: tr onblur or any event outside tr border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row, onblur

How to call function with tr onblur event or how to detect any click-event outside tr border?

Thanks

Html:

```
<tr id="tr_0" class="table" onblur="Dict[@i].Canc(@j)">
    <td id="frst_0" class="tabl">
        <label id="lbl0_0" class="tdLbl0_0">Some name</label>
        <input id="inpt0_0" class="tdinpt0" type="text" size="10" hidden onblur="Dict[@i].CheckInput0(@j)" />
    </td>
    <td id="sec_0" class="tabl" onclick="Dict[@i].EditInput1(@j)">
        <label id="lbl1_0" class="tdLbl1">Value</label>
        <input id="inpt1_0" class="tdinpt1" type="number" max="99" min="0" style="width: 38px" hidden onblur="Dict[@i].CheckInput1(@j)" onfocus="Dict[@i].ClearInput1(@j)" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button id="suc_0" class="tdbtn" hidden onclick="Dict[@i].Suc(@j)">Success</button>
        <button id="edit_0" class="tdbtn" onclick="Dict[@i].Edit(@j)">Edit</button>
        <button id="del_0" class="tdbtn" onclick="Dict[@i].Del(@j)">Delete</button>
        <button id="canc_0" class="tdbtn" onclick="Dict[@i].Canc(@j)" hidden>Cancel</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jQuery.closest` to see if the target element is inside a `tr` or a `tr` like this:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if($(e.target).closest("tr").length)
    alert("tr was clicked!");
  else
    alert("no tr was clicked!");
});
```

If you want to just check if the element clicked is a `tr` or not then use `jQuery.is` like this:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is("tr"))
    alert("tr was clicked!");
  else
    alert("no tr was clicked!");
});
```

**Example of the first case:**

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest("tr").length) // if the length is != 0 (a tr is found)
    alert("tr was clicked!");
  else                                  // otherwise ...
    alert("no tr was clicked!");
});
```

```css
tr {
  background: #F99;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tr_0" class="table" onblur="Dict[@i].Canc(@j)">
    <td id="frst_0" class="tabl">
      <label id="lbl0_0" class="tdLbl0_0">Some name</label>
      <input id="inpt0_0" class="tdinpt0" type="text" size="10" hidden onblur="Dict[@i].CheckInput0(@j)" />
    </td>
    <td id="sec_0" class="tabl" onclick="Dict[@i].EditInput1(@j)">
      <label id="lbl1_0" class="tdLbl1">Value</label>
      <input id="inpt1_0" class="tdinpt1" type="number" max="99" min="0" style="width: 38px" hidden onblur="Dict[@i].CheckInput1(@j)" onfocus="Dict[@i].ClearInput1(@j)" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="suc_0" class="tdbtn" hidden onclick="Dict[@i].Suc(@j)">Success</button>
      <button id="edit_0" class="tdbtn" onclick="Dict[@i].Edit(@j)">Edit</button>
      <button id="del_0" class="tdbtn" onclick="Dict[@i].Del(@j)">Delete</button>
      <button id="canc_0" class="tdbtn" onclick="Dict[@i].Canc(@j)" hidden>Cancel</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Example of the second case:**

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is("tr"))     // if the target of the click is a tr
    alert("tr was clicked!");
  else                          // otherwise
    alert("no tr was clicked!");
});
```

```css
tr {
  background: #F99;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="tr_0" class="table" onblur="Dict[@i].Canc(@j)">
    <td id="frst_0" class="tabl">
      <label id="lbl0_0" class="tdLbl0_0">Some name</label>
      <input id="inpt0_0" class="tdinpt0" type="text" size="10" hidden onblur="Dict[@i].CheckInput0(@j)" />
    </td>
    <td id="sec_0" class="tabl" onclick="Dict[@i].EditInput1(@j)">
      <label id="lbl1_0" class="tdLbl1">Value</label>
      <input id="inpt1_0" class="tdinpt1" type="number" max="99" min="0" style="width: 38px" hidden onblur="Dict[@i].CheckInput1(@j)" onfocus="Dict[@i].ClearInput1(@j)" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <button id="suc_0" class="tdbtn" hidden onclick="Dict[@i].Suc(@j)">Success</button>
      <button id="edit_0" class="tdbtn" onclick="Dict[@i].Edit(@j)">Edit</button>
      <button id="del_0" class="tdbtn" onclick="Dict[@i].Del(@j)">Delete</button>
      <button id="canc_0" class="tdbtn" onclick="Dict[@i].Canc(@j)" hidden>Cancel</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That what you meant by _outside the border of tr_, right?

Comment: @Gamos Please carify more!

Comment: $(e.target).closest("tr").length - works perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: Your welcome! But didn't you say a few moments ago that _it worked for every click even for elements inside tr_? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, your top solution - is what i want, and can you tell me pls, how to chech it by id of tr?

Comment: @Gamos if you want to check for a specific `tr` then just pass whatever selector you want for `closest`. If you want to check against a specific id for example then just replace this `$(e.target).closest("tr").length` with this: `$(e.target).closest("#IDOfTrHere").length`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the click events on the **document** itself, and check the `event.target` object, if parents of the event.target don't contain the `tr`, manually trigger the `blur` event on `tr`.

```
$.fn.bindBlur = function(callback){
    this.each(function(){
        var that = this;
        $(document).on("click", function(e){
            if(that.is($(e.target) || that.has($(e.target))){
                return callback();
            }
        });
    });    
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try it